# Removing "wpautop" (auto <p> tags) only on certain pages?

Tags: php, functions, filters, the-content, wp-autop

I'm using the `remove_filter` in **functions.php** to remove the auto insertion of `<p>` and `<br>` tags on my wordpress site.

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

But one of our pages (wiki) is being dynamically created and to make a long story short, it relies on the `<p>` tags.

How and where should I write an `if` statement that targets only certain pages to apply the `remove_filter` to?

I've tried placing this code in the both the **functions.php**, **front-page.php**, and **page.php** files but nothing seems to work.

```
<?php if ( !is_page( 'wiki') ) { 
  remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
  remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
} ?>
```

Comment: Did you put the code in a function called via `wp` or a later hook? Because you should, for `is_page()` to give you the proper results.

Comment: you can also write your own content filtering function and use that on get_post_field('post_content') with more or less the same result. the_content filter runs about 5 filters including wpautop. Run just 4 of them. There are potential solutions this is just one.